# Error: Reference not found. Binding an ActionListener method to a button in <af:button>

Tags: jsf, parameter-passing, actionlistener, oracle-adf

I am creating a program using Jdeveloper 12c.  This program will use a user generated input of an address which is then marked on a map.  The map used is the thematic map feature of Jdeveloper.  The problem I am having is with the button's actionListener.  It is supposed to initiate the addLocation Method of the LLConverter class that takes the input (in a RichInputText), converts it into latitude and longitude (via a lot of conversions, RTF-->String (so I can use GeoCoder to convert to Lat and Long) --> float (for the thematic map), which then plots those values onto the map. The ActionListener `#{AddButton.addLocation}` isn't recognized

Here's my two classes:

```
 public class LLConverter {

private static final String GEO_CODE_SERVER = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?";
private static RichInputText addressBind;

private List<LocationDetail> mapDetail = new ArrayList<LocationDetail>();

public LLConverter() {
        // Add Default location to map
        LocationDetail location = new LocationDetail();

        location.setLongitude((float) 105.0781);
        location.setLatitude((float) 40.5592);
        mapDetail.add(location);

        location = new LocationDetail();

        location.setLongitude((float) 91.5333);
        location.setLatitude((float) 41.6667);
        mapDetail.add(location);

        System.out.println("List is-" + mapDetail);
    }    
public void addLocation(ActionEvent actionEvent, String addressBind)throws IOException, BadLocationException{


        RTFEditorKit rtfParser = new RTFEditorKit();
        Document document = rtfParser.createDefaultDocument();
        ByteArrayInputStream bytearrayinputstream=new ByteArrayInputStream(addressBind.getBytes());
        rtfParser.read(bytearrayinputstream,document,0);
        String code = document.getText(0, document.getLength());

        String response = getLocation(code);

        String[] result = parseLocation(response);

        float[] numbers = new float[result.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < result.length; ++i) {
                float number = Float.parseFloat(result[i]);
                float rounded = (int) Math.round(number * 1000) / 1000f;
                numbers[i] = rounded;
            }
        float lat = numbers[0];
        float lon = numbers[1];

        LocationDetail location = new LocationDetail();
        location = new LocationDetail();
        location.setLongitude(lat);
        location.setLatitude(lon);
        mapDetail.add(location);



    System.out.println("List is-" + mapDetail);

}

public void setAddressBind(RichInputText addressBind) {
    this.addressBind = addressBind;
}

public RichInputText getAddressBind() {
    return addressBind;
}
private static String getLocation(String code)
{
    String address = buildUrl(code);

    String content = null;

    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(address);

        InputStream stream = url.openStream();

        try
        {
            int available = stream.available();

            byte[] bytes = new byte[available];

            stream.read(bytes);

            content = new String(bytes);
        }
        finally
        {
            stream.close();
        }

        return (String) content.toString();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private static String buildUrl(String code)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    builder.append(GEO_CODE_SERVER);

    builder.append("address=");
    builder.append(code.replaceAll(" ", "+"));
    builder.append("&sensor=false");

    return builder.toString();
}

private static String[] parseLocation(String response)
{
    // Look for location using brute force.
    // There are much nicer ways to do this, e.g. with Google's JSON library: Gson
    //     https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

    String[] lines = response.split("\n");

    String lat = null;
    String lng = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
    {
        if ("\"location\" : {".equals(lines[i].trim()))
        {
            lat = getOrdinate(lines[i+1]);
            lng = getOrdinate(lines[i+2]);
            break;
        }
    }

    return new String[] {lat, lng};
}

private static String getOrdinate(String s)
{
    String[] split = s.trim().split(" ");

    if (split.length < 1)
    {
        return null;
    }

    String ord = split[split.length - 1];

    if (ord.endsWith(","))
    {
        ord = ord.substring(0, ord.length() - 1);
    }

    // Check that the result is a valid double
    Double.parseDouble(ord);

    return ord;
}

public void setMapDetail(List mapDetail) {
this.mapDetail = mapDetail;
}

public List getMapDetail() {
return mapDetail;
}
```

AND

```
public class LocationDetail {
private String location;
private float latitude; // Latitude of location
private float longitude; // Longitude of Location

    public LocationDetail() {
        super();
    }

public void setLatitude(float latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public float getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(float longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public float getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }          
}
```

And the code for my map, which is a jsf page.

```
<af:document title="Map.jsf" id="d1">
    <af:form id="f1">
        <af:pageTemplate viewId="/oracle/templates/threeColumnTemplate.jspx" id="pt1"
                         >
            <f:facet name="center">
                <dvt:thematicMap basemap="usa" id="tm1" >
                    <?audit suppress oracle.adf.dvt.acc-compreqsummary?>
                    <dvt:areaLayer layer="counties" id="al1" />
                    <dvt:pointDataLayer id="dl1" value="#{viewScope.LLConverter.mapDetail}" var="row">
                        <dvt:pointLocation id="pl1"  type="pointXY" pointY="#{row.longitude}" 
                        pointX="#{row.latitude}">
                            </dvt:pointLocation>
                    </dvt:pointDataLayer>
                </dvt:thematicMap>
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="header"/>
            <f:facet name="end"/>
            <f:facet name="start">
                <af:inputText label="Address" id="it2" binding="#{viewScope.LLConverter.addressBind}">
                </af:inputText>
                <af:button text= "GetLocation" id="b1"
                           actionListener="#{AddButton.addLocation}"/>
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="branding"/>
            <f:facet name="copyright"/>
            <f:facet name="status"/>
        </af:pageTemplate>
    </af:form>
</af:document>
```

Addbutton is the name I gave the bean, whose class is LLConverter and method is addLocation.  I've tried renaming and creating the bean a crazy number of times and differing scopes (there isn't one here, but I've tried view and request scopes).

I just keep getting the same error, "Reference addLocation not found."

The error allows me to auto-generate the appropriate method into the LLConverter class, but when I put in my code into that method, it gives me the error again.  Which leads me to believe that it might be the class code, not the method binding.

Any thoughts or ideas are greatly appreciated! And of course, I'm sure I missed some necessary information, so please ask away!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actionListener can only have an ActionEvent as parameter (so remove everything else).
If you want to send extra parameters, you can use the following logic:

On the page:

```
<af:button text="button" id="cb1"
                  actionListener="#{myBean.myActionListener}">
  <f:attribute name="param" value="value"/>
</af:button>
```

In the bean:

```
public void myActionListener(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
  String param = (String)actionEvent.getComponent().getAttributes().get("param");
}
```

**OR** you could use your bindings of course.

Comment: Hey, since you're familiar with my code I have another question.  Of course if you want me to ask this again in a new question, I am more than willing.  The pointX and pointY of my jsf page are throwing errors as well.  They say "row.latitude" not found and "row.longitude" not found.  I'm not finding a lot of documentation on this feature of maps, but from what I have seen, this is how its supposed to be written.  But I may just be 100% doing this wrong. Thanks

Comment: @MMM I'm not so familiar with dvt components, so it's better to ask a new question.